# No-argument constructor in Spark Shell / Scala REPL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, read-eval-print-loop

In spark-shell (which uses scala-repl), it seems impossible to make a (case) class which has the default constructor (i.e. no-argument constructor):

```
scala> case class Hello(i: Int) {
      |   def this() = this(0)
      | }
defined class Hello

scala> classOf[Hello].getName
res1: String = Hello

scala> classOf[Hello].getConstructors()
res2: Array[java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_]] = Array(public Hello($iw), public Hello($iw,int))
```

This makes Jackson fail to deserialize something into this class, because there isn't a simple way to construct an instance of that class using reflection.

Is it possible to make a case class have a default constructor in spark shell?

Comment: Reproduced this code got `Array[java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_]] = Array(public Hello(), public Hello(int))` . Which scala version do you use?

Comment: Same result as Odomontois, using Scala 2.11.6 and Scala REPL. However with Spark shell I get the same result as you @lyomi. But new Hello() works as expected: res1: Hello = Hello(0), even in Spark shell

Comment: I could make zero-argument constructor in scala shell, but had no luck in spark-shell, in both 2.10 and 2.11. `Hello()` should work because syntactically the shell is within an instance of the class `$iw`, which seems to be generated by the repl, and `Hello` is an inner class of that.

Comment: Can you please include _two_ listings? One that shows the "good" behavior in the Scala shell and one that shows the "bad" behavior in the Spark shell? I found that `new Hello()` works in both environments and `Hello()` works in neither. (Which I think is what Odomontois and Björn also found.)

Comment: @DanielDarabos FYI, you can't do `Hello()` because the compiler doesn't add corresponding `apply()` method to the companion object, and this has nothing to do with REPL except that you don't know **it

Comment: I'm having the same issue -- seems to be a recognized problem:
http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Problem-creating-objects-through-reflection-td6405.html

You can see it with a simple test case:
    class X {}
    classOf[X].getConstructor()
works fine in scala repl, fails in spark scala repl

Comment: jupyter-scala has the same problem and the example notebook is here where none of the other suggestions (inside an object, etc) worked either
https://gist.github.com/kmader/d7299dc542cfab974b80