# Error calling `JValue.extract` from distributed operations in spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, json4s

I am trying to use the case class extraction feature of json4s in Spark,
ie calling `jvalue.extract[MyCaseClass]`. It works fine if I bring the `JValue` objects into the master and do the extraction there, but the same calls fail in the workers:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val sqx = sqlContext

val data = sc.textFile(inpath).coalesce(2000)

case class PageView(
 client:  Option[String]
)

def extract(json: JValue) = {
  implicit def formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
  Try(json.extract[PageView]).toOption
}

val json = data.map(parse(_)).sample(false, 1e-6).cache()

// count initial inputs
val raw = json.count 


// count successful extractions locally -- same value as above
val loc = json.toLocalIterator.flatMap(extract).size

// distributed count -- always zero
val dist = json.flatMap(extract).count // always returns zero

// this throws  "org.json4s.package$MappingException: Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor"
json.map(x => {implicit def formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats; x.extract[PageView]}).count
```

The implicit for `Formats` is defined locally in the `extract` function since DefaultFormats is not serializable and defining it at top level caused it to be serialized to for transmission to the workers rather than constructed there. I think the proble still has something to do with the remote initialization of `DefaultFormats`, but I am not sure what it is.

When I call the `extract` method directly, insted of my `extract` function, like in the last example, it no longer complains about serialization but just throws an error that the JSON does not match the expected structure.

How can I get the extraction to work when distributed to the workers?

---

### Edit

@WesleyMiao has reproduced the problem and found that it is specific to spark-shell. He reports that this code works as a standalone application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same exception as yours when running your code in spark-shell. However when I turn your code into a real spark app and submit it to a standalone spark cluster, I got expected results with no exception.

Below is the code I put in a simple spark app.

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq("""{"client":"Michael"}""", """{"client":"Wesley"}"""))

val json = data.map(parse(_))

val dist = json.mapPartitions { jsons =>
  implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
  jsons.map(_.extract[PageView])
}

dist.collect() foreach println
```

And when I run it using spark-submit, I got the following result.

```
PageView(Some(Michael))                                                                                                                                       
PageView(Some(Wesley))
```

And I am also sure that it is running not in "local[*]" mode.

Now I suspect the reason we got exceptions while running in spark-shell has something to do with the case class PageView definition in spark-shell and how spark-shell serialize / distribute it to executor.

Comment: Thanks for reproducing the error and determining that it is spark-shell specific. What makes you think that the problems is the case class rather than the implicit Formats instance?

Comment: `spark-shell` does something odd with the constructors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592985/no-argument-constructor-in-spark-shell-scala-repl has a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://engineering.sharethrough.com/blog/2013/09/13/top-3-troubleshooting-tips-to-keep-you-sparking/) I would move object creation into the map. I.e. I would have function `createPageViews` that has extract as internal function and will pass `createPageViews` to workers.

More precisely I would use mapPartitions instead of map - so it would have to call `createPageViews` (and it's internal function definition part) only once per partition - and not once per every record.